# Ios MKMapView - get application to navigation via Third-party

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, navigation, mkmapview, direction

I succeed to display address in MKMapView via lat and long.
How can I get list with all the navigation application(Third-party) that installed on my device and select one of them in order to navigate to this address?

How I can know which navigation application installed on user Device?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you solve this problem ?